# How can I control when (or if) file writes are committed to disk?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file that's a big binary blob, and I'm writing an editor for that file. I want to make changes, but don't want them written to disk right away; I want the option of throwing them away without saving them.

What's a good way to do this?

Some things I thought of:

1. Slurp the whole file into memory and edit it there. (What if the file is huge though?)
2. Make a temp file and edit that. (Same problem)
3. Make a file-like object that writes to an internal data structure that sits "in front of" the file.

#3 sounds like it would work. It also sounds like something someone has probably already done, and I just don't know the right search terms to plug into google.

I'm working in Python 3.

Comment: This depends pretty heavily on what kind of file you're working with, as well as whether the format was designed to be editable with few disk writes. "Slurp it" is a very common option, and I've personally worked with programs designed for the "slurp it" approach with terabytes of data (although that takes specialized hardware).

Comment: You could try keeping an elaborate set of diffs for each edit in memory, which you only apply to the actual file upon saving. That's probably the most difficult method, but also the one using the least amount of memory if done right. Obviously depends on the average size of the edits though.

Comment: That "elaborate set of diffs" is more or less what I had in mind with #3. I can do it, but it smells like it should be a solved problem.